# Can we have a post notice for system-recommendation questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, game-recommendation, post-notice

RPG has long allowed [system-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-recommendation) questions under fairly tight tight rules, and every time they pop up the mods are posting a general comment like the following:

> Just a note folks, remember that our sys-rec questions require *good subjective* basis. You must have played the system within the context of the requirements to recommend it. – Brian Ballsun-Stanton

- [Reference](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15296/i-am-looking-for-a-game-to-ease-my-friends-into-role-playing#comment-24959)

This seems like a great thing to have in a post notice, with links to the sys-rec tag wiki and the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

It would be even cooler if this could be automated...

Comment: in the meantime (if you haven't already) setting up a pro-forma comment might be helpful: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116/11042)

Comment: Obsolete: [system recommendations are no longer on-topic](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5747/23970).

Comment: I've added the [status-declined] tag for the reason nitsua60 pointed out.